# Running OpenCl Matrix Multiplication using the CPU host without using FPGA

Tags: opencl, fpga, hpc

I was able to successfully running "Matrix Multiplication Design Example [here](https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/design-examples/design-software/opencl/matrix-multiplication.html)" on my Stratix V FPGA. To compile OpenCL kernel I use the command (Cento 6.9):

aoc device/matrix_mult.cl -o bin/matrix_mult.aocx -fp-relaxed -fpc -no-interleaving=default --board 395_hpc_ab

My question is: I am trying to compare the performance (Execution Time) between

- Matrix Multiplication Design Example using FPGA and
- Matrix Multiplication Design Example without using FPGA

So that, can I compile and run this Matrix Multiplication Design Example on just my host CPU without using my FPGA? how?

Comment: You could time multiplying the same size matrix using the matrix multiply function in a linear algebra library, for example [Intel Math Kernel Library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-tutorial-c-multiplying-matrices-using-dgemm) or ATLAS or OpenBLAS

Comment: You could start from comparing to reference implementation which is in compute_reference() function and run by default. Then perhaps comparing to optimized version as @BenVoigt suggested.